# Не могу поставить коды на class

Tags: php, классы

Не могу поставить коды на class

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");
$count_users = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count_users) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<a href="'.$row['user_url'].'">'.$row['user_name'].'</a>';
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
$template = new template();
$template->body='<div class="user_list">Нужно поставить здесь!</div>';
?>
```

---

Так не получается

```
<?php
$template = new template();
$template->body='<div class="user_list">'
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");
    $count_users = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count_users) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<a href="'.$row['user_url'].'">'.$row['user_name'].'</a>';
        }
    }
'</div>';
?>
```

---

Мне нужно типа такой

```
<div class="user_list">
    <a href="1">Andrey</a>
    <a href="2">Nikolay</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не понял или у вас плохо с русским языком, или вы плаваете в терминологии....на какие классы какие коды..wtf?

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, что требуется.

Comment: @0xdef В php есть такой класс да например `class template { public body; }`. И я открою `$template = new template();` и не могу поставить некоторый код `$template->body='<div class="user_list">Нужно поставить здесь!</div>';`. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @cheops Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом: поместить ответ, формируемый из базы данных, в какую-то промежуточную переменную, а затем интерполировать ее в шаблон.

```
<?php
$template = new template();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");
$count_users = mysql_num_rows($result);
$result_str = '';
if ($count_users) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_str .= '<a href="'.$row['user_url'].'">'.$row['user_name'].'</a>';
    }
}
$template->body = "<div class=\"user_list\">$result_str</div>";
?>
```

PS При извлечении из базы данных, лучше постепенно отказываться от расширения mysql, так как оно признано устаревшим и удалено из PHP 7. В качестве альтернатив следует использовать расширения mysqli или PDO.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое я новичок :)